# How to add a type of listener to a JTable (Java)?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, action, listener

I have a column with plain text in it.

If the user double-clicks a row in that column, the column allows itself to be edited for that row (as it should).

I need something to detect when that text is done with being edited (when the user hits the enter key, for example). When that happens, I need something to get the row ID of that change (0-based of course).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: If you plan to update the model based on the row number, consider the approach shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350445/how-do-i-get-the-cellrow-when-there-is-an-itemevent-in-the-jcombobox-within-the-c/7356518#7356518).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add a listener to the TableModel:

```
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

      public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
         // your code goes here;
      }
    });
```

[TableModelEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelEvent.html) contains row and column number and type of modification.

Comment: How would I get the row of whatever it detects?

Comment: +1. The TableModelEvent has access to the TableModel so you can use the getValueAt(...) method to get the row id.

Comment: the only ints that this gives me is the first row and the last row - isn't this method ONLY called when ONE value has changed?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to get the location of the click in terms of row and column would be this:

```
table.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
        int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        int column = table.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        if (row >= 0 && column >= 0) {
            ......

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a mixture of both. I have a column with plain text in it. If the user double-clicks the row in that column, the column allows itself to be edited for that row. I need something to detect when that text is done with being edited (like when the user hits the enter key. When that happens, I need something to get the row ID of that change (0-based of course).

Comment: Is it a bad smell? Use MouseEvents while you have access TableModelListener?