# JColorChooser in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, jcolorchooser

[image]

I have a very simple class displaying a jTable, where in column1 I have added a combobox

```
public class Table extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   public Table() {
    initComponents();
    TableColumn name = jTableProva.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);

    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
    combo.addItem("Rain");
    combo.addItem("Snow");
    combo.addItem("Sunny");

    name.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combo));
}
```

My questions:

1) I don't know why combos always appears hidden or "behind" cells when run.

2) I would like to add a `JColorChooser` in column 2. How can I accomplish this using the Netbeans swing component code? I have added a `JColorChooser` by drag and drop from palette.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to do this in code, not with drag-and-drop. Read the tutorials on [How to Use JTables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and you'll see how to do this. Pay particular attention to the section on creating custom editors.

Comment: Also, as to your first question, can you show an image of the problem (or link to an image if you're not able to show one yet)?

Comment: Picture added: as you can see, no combos is visible in column 1, but there is a combobox on each row for column 1

Comment: The combo is used as the column's cell *editor* not its *renderer*, so it makes sense that it won't appear unless you are editing the cell -- nor do you want it to appear until then.

Answer (score 2):

Absent your [sscce](http://sscce.org/), it's not clear what the problem might be. You can compare what you're doing with this working [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513) that shows a `DefaultCellEditor` having a `JComboBox`. [*Using a Combo Box as an Editor*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox) also shows a `JComboBox`; [*Using Other Editors*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor) shows a `JButton` that launches a `JColorChooser`.