# How to make a jtable cell listen to changes from another cell

Tags: java, jtable, cell, custom-cell, focuslistener

Please help. I have two cells from a jtable, one ID and one Description. The ID and Description are both custom combobox. What I am trying to do is when the ID loses its focus or changes its value, the Description will update based on the value on the ID. How do I do that?

Here is my code for the implementation of both cells:

```
TableColumn subAccountCol = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(table.findColumn("SubAccount"));

    javax.swing.JComboBox accountCbx = new javax.swing.JComboBox(Account.toArray());
    javax.swing.JComboBox accountDescCbx = new javax.swing.JComboBox(AccountDesc.toArray());

    CompleteText.enable(accountCbx);
    CompleteText.enable(accountDescCbx);

    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(table.findColumn("Account")).setCellEditor(new ComboBoxCellEditor(accountCbx));
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(table.findColumn("Account Description")).setCellEditor(new ComboBoxCellEditor(accountDescCbx));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cell editor will ultmately call the method `setValueAt()` on your table model. In this table model, simply update the linked cell value in addition to the edited celle value, and fire the appropriate change event for both cells.

```
public MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel() {
    // ...

    // modifies the value for the given cell
    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
        Foo foo = this.list.get(row);
        if (column == INDEX_OF_ID_COLUMN) {
            foo.setId(value); // change the ID
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, column); // signal the the ID has changed
            // and now also change the description
            String newDescription = createNewDescription(value);
            foo.setDescription(newDescription);
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, INDEX_OF_DESCRIPTION_COLUMN); // signal the the description has changed  
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Umm.. I didnt get that. Sorry! Can you explain it further or a pseudocode maybe? Thanks btw.

Comment: I was able to come up with my own solution. I used the tableChanged from the TableModelListener. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @user1349213: You should do this in the _model_, as JB shows; there's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513).