# how to edit all cells in a row with the cell editor of first cell in the row in the Jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I have a JTable with  6 columns. for column 0 and 1 i have created a comboBox as editor.
I want all the cells in the same row be edited when user select an item from combobox of column 0.

**Does any one know if it is the best way or is there other way much better?**

```
JTable table = new JTable();// a table with 6 columns
TableColumn column0 = tabel.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
comboBox = new JComboBox(summary.getGenerics());
column0.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
column0.setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer());
comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
              String selectedItem = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
               table.setValueAt("class" , table.getSelectedRow() , 1);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513) overrides `getValueAt()` to condition the value returned by a dependent column based on the selection in a column having a `JComboBox` editor. Any dependent column should be *non*-editable, and any `TableModelListener` should be notified, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13628183/230513).