# Java Jtable spreadsheet like format

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have problems regarding implementing `JTable`, specifically the `AbstractTableModel`. I can create and show data from `JTable` but my current scenario is different from my usually scenario.

What I want to do is to make my `JTable` accept an input from user and I want to put other components inside the `JTable`

Lets say for every row there is a `JComboBox`, `JTextField` and a `JCheckBox`, however when I start to implement the `JTable` model (`AbstractTableModel`) I don't know how can I put those components to my `JTable`?

Since the method `getValue` from `AbstractTableModel` return type is of object data types. Do you have any workaround for this kind of problems and by the ways I hate using `DefaultTableModel` since it lacks flexibility as much as possible I want an `AbstractTableModel` :) help is really appreciated.

Comment: `TableModel` has a method called `getColumnClass` which returns a `Class` type of the specified column. The `JTable` uses this information to look up the required editor and renderer to use (based on the class type).  Check out [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: thanks I'll read this, well you look at that actually this is also what I've search for still thanks for the fast answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely start with [*How to Use Tables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and study the [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#eg) there. While a `JTable` ins't a spreadsheet, you *can* calculate derived values in your table's model. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513) shows how to use a `JComboBox` to update other cells in the same row, and these [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13628183/230513) similarly contrast the two `TableModel` implementations you mention. Finally, you can use an available `ScriptEngine` to evaluate simple arithmetic expressions. For example, the example below prints `42.0`.

```
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByExtension("js");
try {
    System.out.println(engine.eval("5 * 8 + 2"));
} catch (ScriptException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```