# Why do we have to use a TableModel for a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

If I want to use a `JTable` in Java it seems to me for adding rows and doing alters from behind a button or so I always have to use a `TableModel` (this could be the default one or one created by your own) But my question is: Why do we have to use this. I can't find this in any of the posts I saw. Can someone explain how this works and why it is necessary? And why we can't just add rows to the `JTable` without a model.

It seems to me that if you want to just show a few records but at creation you don't know all the rows yet it would be easier to just do something like a `table.add()` to add the row.
You can create the table with data inside without a model attached to it. So why not add data?

Or am I just wrong and can you add also data without a model?

Comment: and there is significant difference betweens DeafultTableModel and AbstractTableModeel

Comment: @Paul Vargas not theoretically all JComponents has model,

Comment: @PaulVargas I would also suggest it was some from the Swing team ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I already know how to use it. I just wanted to know why we have to use it. I think it is good if you work with resultsets and a database but if you just want to show some data I find it overload, although it might be only a few lines of code. So because of that I asked my question here.

Comment: The basic design philosophy of Swing is based loosely on the MVC model. This requires all view components to be controlled in part by a separate data model. In separates responsibility and increases flexibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TableModel` interface defines the *minimum* methods needed by a `JTable` (view) to render its content (model). `AbstractTableModel` is an abstract implementation that provides the event plumbing and leaves just [three methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) that *must* be overridden. `DefaultTableModel` goes on to include an internal data model based on `Vector` and convenient methods to alter that internal model. See [*Creating a Table Model*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) for a comparison and these contrasting [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13628183/230513).

Comment: Is the TableModel "controller", "view" or the "model" in MVC?

Comment: @KorayTugay: It is a _model_; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Comment: I am not sure if I fully agree it is the "Model". I think it still falls in the "View". A TableModel does not implement and business logic or encapsulate any data, it seems to be more concerned with presentation to me.

Comment: @KorayTugay: I would argue that a `TableModel` encapsulates _all_ of the data displayed by the table and contains _no_ business logic. As comments are not suitable for extended discussion, your might want to pose a question on this topic.