# how to let JTable listens to user's selection and updates a cell value

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I am new to JAVA and I am trying to make a JTable. What I want is that whenever a user make a selection from the comboBox in the Jtable, the Jtable will put the current date in the cell next to the comboBox. I wrote a code, but the code cannot upate the cell value. Here is my code(I just want the Jtable to insert "a" at row 1 column 4 for right now).

```
 public class GChamber extends JPanel {
private boolean DEBUG = true;
 ListSelectionModel listSelectionModel;
public GChamber() {

    ...

    JTable table1 = new JTable(new Table1());
    listSelectionModel = table1.getSelectionModel();

    table1.setSelectionModel(listSelectionModel);

    ...

    TableColumn TestName=table1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
    final JComboBox comboBox= new JComboBox();

    //Setup comboBox. The data of comboBox is from another Jtable.
    for(int i=0;i<table2rowlength;i++)
    {
     comboBox.addItem(Listofdiease[i]);
    }

    comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    TestName.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

             String userinput = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
             Table1 temp=new Table1();
              for(int i=0;i<table2rowlength;i++)
                {
                  if (userinput.equals(Listofdiease[i])) {
                      temp.setValueAt("a", 1, 4);

                    }
                }

        }
    });


   ....


}
public class Table1 extends AbstractTableModel  {


        String[] cName1 = {"1","2","3","4","5", "6"};
         Object[][] data1 = {
                {"CC040-2", new Integer(1),"", "","",""}, 
                {"CC040-2", new Integer(2),"Rowing", "", "",""},
                {"CC040-2", new Integer(3),"Knitting", "", "",""},
                {"CC040-2", new Integer(4),"Speed reading", "", "",""},
                {"CC040-2", new Integer(5),"Pool", "", "",""},
                {"CC040-2", new Integer(6),"Pool", "", "",""},
                {"CC040-2", new Integer(7),"Pool", "", "",""},
                {"CC040-2", new Integer(8),"Pool", "", "",""},
                {"CC040-2", new Integer(9),"Pool", "", "",""},
                {"CC040-2", new Integer(10),"Pool", "", "",""},
                {"CC040-2", new Integer(11),"Pool", "", "",""},
                {"CC040-2", new Integer(12),"Pool", "", "",""},
                {"CEA003", new Integer(13),"Pool","", "",""},
                {"CEA003", new Integer(14),"Pool", "", "",""},
                {"CEA003", new Integer(15),"Pool", "", "",""},
                {"CEA003", new Integer(16),"Pool", "", "",""},
                {"CEA004", new Integer(17),"Pool", "", "",""},
                {"CEA004", new Integer(18),"Pool", "", "",""},
                {"CEA004", new Integer(19),"Pool", "", "",""},
                {"CEA004", new Integer(20),"Pool", "", "",""},
        };




        public int getColumnCount() {
            return cName1.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data1.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return cName1[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data1[row][col];
        }


        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }


        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {

            if (col < 2) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }


        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                                   + " to " + value
                                   + " (an instance of "
                                   + value.getClass() + ")");
            }

            data1[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("New value of data:");
                printDebugData();
            }
        }

        private void printDebugData() {
            int numRows = getRowCount();
            int numCols = getColumnCount();

            for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
                System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
                for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + data1[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }


        public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {


        }
```

}

Is there anyone can tell me why this code does not work and how to fix it?

Comment: The table does not directly modify the state of the model. It instead, the table will call your models .setValueAt,ethos. It's at this point you would update the state of the model as you need to

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use one of the approaches suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513). If the dependent column is *not* editable, simply return the desired result from your `TableModel` based on the combo selection. If the dependent column *is* editable, use either approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13628183/230513).

[image]