# JTable unable to change cell value

Tags: swing, jtable, jframe, global-variables, tablecelleditor

I have created a method to created `JTable` as per below:

```
public void refTable(String jobNo) {
        Report rp = new Report();
        final String noJob = jobNo;

        Map<Integer, String> jMap = rp.getReportInfo(jobNo);
        Map<Integer, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(jMap);

        String[] row = new String[sortedMap.size()];
        Integer[] no = new Integer[sortedMap.size()];
        String[] stat = new String[sortedMap.size()];
        Boolean[] dev = new Boolean[sortedMap.size()];
        String[] remark = new String[sortedMap.size()];
        Boolean[] rem = new Boolean[sortedMap.size()];
        userRemark = new String[sortedMap.size()];
        tabSize = sortedMap.size();
        int i = 0;

        for (Integer key : sortedMap.keySet()) {
            no[i] = key;
            String[] val = sortedMap.get(key).split("###");
            if (val[0].trim().equals("DEV")) {
                stat[i] = "FAIL";
            } else {
                stat[i] = val[0].trim();
            }
            row[i] = val[1].trim();
            dev[i] = false;
            remark[i] = "";
            //remark[i] = false;
           //if(userRemark1[i]!=null)
            userRemark[i] = RemarkDropDownList.userOthersReamrk;
            //else
            //userRemark[i] ="";   
            rem[i] = false;
            i++;
        }

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.fireTableDataChanged();
        jTable1.setModel(model);

        model.addColumn("No:", no);
        model.addColumn("Status:", stat);
        model.addColumn("Details:", row);
        model.addColumn("Non-Deviation", dev);
        model.addColumn("Remarks", remark);
        model.addColumn("Remove", rem);
        model.addColumn("UR", userRemark);

        TableColumn col1 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        col1.setPreferredWidth(30);

        TableColumn col2 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        col2.setPreferredWidth(30);

        TableColumn col3 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
        TextRenderer renderer = new TextRenderer();
        col3.setCellRenderer(renderer);
        col3.setPreferredWidth(350);

        CellRenderer cellRender = new CellRenderer();
        TableColumn col4 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
        col4.setCellEditor(jTable1.getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class));
        col4.setCellRenderer(cellRender);
        col4.setPreferredWidth(50);

        TableButton buttonEditor = new TableButton("Button");
        buttonEditor.addTableButtonListener(new TableButtonListener() {
            //@Override
            public void tableButtonClicked(int row, int col) {
                RemarkDropDownList rmk = new RemarkDropDownList(noJob, row);
                rmk.setVisible(true);
                //userRemark1[row] = RemarkDropDownList.userOthersReamrk;
                //String test = RemarkDropDownList.userOthersReamrk;
            }
        });
        TableColumn col5 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
        col5.setCellRenderer(buttonEditor);
        col5.setCellEditor(buttonEditor);

        TableColumn col6 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5);
        col6.setCellEditor(jTable1.getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class));
        col6.setCellRenderer(jTable1.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class));
        col6.setPreferredWidth(50);

        jTable1.setShowGrid(true);
        jTable1.setGridColor(Color.BLACK);
        jTable1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    }
```

In my `JTable` I've created a button in column 5 like this.

```
TableButton buttonEditor = new TableButton("Button");
        buttonEditor.addTableButtonListener(new TableButtonListener() {
            //@Override
            public void tableButtonClicked(int row, int col) {
                RemarkDropDownList rmk = new RemarkDropDownList(noJob, row);
                rmk.setVisible(true);
                //userRemark1[row] = RemarkDropDownList.userOthersReamrk;
                //String test = RemarkDropDownList.userOthersReamrk;
            }
        });
        TableColumn col5 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
        col5.setCellRenderer(buttonEditor);
        col5.setCellEditor(buttonEditor);
```

The button basically create a new `JFrame` with combobox inside it like this.

```
public class RemarkDropDownList extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public static String userOthersReamrk = "test";
    private String userSelectedItem = "File Issue";
    String jobno;
    int rowNo;
  public RemarkDropDownList() {
        initComponents();
        this.lblOthers.setVisible(false);
        this.txtOthers.setVisible(false);
    }
  public RemarkDropDownList(String jobNo, int row) {
        initComponents();
        this.lblOthers.setVisible(false);
        this.txtOthers.setVisible(false);
        this.jobno = jobNo;
        this.rowNo = row;
    }
 private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:    
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();
         userSelectedItem = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
                if(userSelectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("others"))
                {
                    this.lblOthers.setVisible(true);
                    this.txtOthers.setVisible(true);                    
                }
                else
                {
                    this.lblOthers.setVisible(false);
                    this.txtOthers.setVisible(false);
                }
    }  
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
       if(userSelectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("others"))
       {
        userOthersReamrk = txtOthers.getText().toString();
        if(userOthersReamrk == null || userOthersReamrk.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter Remark");            
        }
       }
       else
       {
           userOthersReamrk = userSelectedItem;
           //String [] remark = new String [1000];
           ///remark[rowNo] = userOthersReamrk;
           ReportPanelMin rpm = new ReportPanelMin();
           //rpm.userRemark1[rowNo] = remark[rowNo];
           rpm.refTable(jobno);
           this.setVisible(false);
       }       
    }  
}
```

Everything is working, but the last part. I've created a static global variable (`userOthersReamrk`) in `RemarkDropDownList` class (the new class) to hold user drop down selected value. I call the `refTable` function again to reload the table so i can assign the `userOthersReamrk` value to column no 7 like this `userRemark = new String[sortedMap.size()];`. When i debug, I can see the user selected value is assigned to`userRemark` array but its not population in the table. The column showing the default value `test` which i decalred in `RemarkDropDownList`. I know the code is so long, but i post everything to give better understanding on what im doing. What/where i need to make change so my user's selected value is shown in column 7 instead the default value.

Comment: Please show a SSCCE (you can't really expect anybody to walk through that heap of snippets, can you :-)

Comment: Some examples are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17960587/230513).