# Undesirable change in displayed fields in JTable

Tags: java, swing, model, jtable

at the moment I have an app that allows me to display data in a Jtable and then when I double click the Jtable this open a little window to edit only 3 fields, comments, expiration date and description. I update the this values (whit a `preparedStatement`) the thing is that everytime that I make an update to the database my table just refresh itself, changing the dateFormat with the new value that I've just inserted in my other window but with a different format!. How is this possible?

I' don't understand this because the only I only set a model to the table when I press my "search" button which contains the following code:

```
ArrayList<FiltrosResumen> filtrosResumenList = MainFrame.dataBase.searchFiltroResumen(query);
        FiltrosResumenTableModel resumenModel = new FiltrosResumenTableModel(filtrosResumenList);
        this.resumenTable.setModel(resumenModel);
        hideColumns(1);
```

[image: SS]

I'm using a custom table model containing all the table Fields, so first as you can see I colect all the rows from the database into a ArrayList from a custom object "`FiltrosResumen`", then I pass this to the constructor from my customTable model "`FiltrosResumenTableModel`" which extends `AbstractTableMode` I'm not using any special renders the most important methods are

```
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return this.filtrosResumen.get(rowIndex).getIdFiltro();
            //....
            //case 9:
           default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        FiltrosResumen filtroResumen = new FiltrosResumen();
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                filtroResumen = this.filtrosResumen.get(rowIndex);
                filtroResumen.setIdFiltro(Long.parseLong(aValue.toString()));
                this.fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
                break;}
             //....
            //case 9: 

            }
```

And the constructor

```
  public FiltrosResumenTableModel(List<FiltrosResumen> filtrosResumen) {
        this.filtrosResumen = filtrosResumen;

    }
```

And as I stated before, the database does not interact directly whit the table since storing the query result in a ArrayList, and then sending this to the constructor of my customTableModel.

**EDIT:** In order to change the value from one of the rows items I send a `FiltrosResumen` Object in this way:

```
FiltrosResumenTableModel modelo = (FiltrosResumenTableModel) this.resumenTable.getModel();
resumen = modelo.getResumen(row);
EditResumenIF editConexionesIF = new EditResumenIF(resumen);
```

**EDIT:** Passing a the resumen object to a InternalFrame Constructor (EditResumenIF).So in this new InternalFrame (EditResumenIF) I assign the values to a JCalendar and a JTextField to change the values and then save them. Afther the same object received by the constructor to a method that does the query and then return a string, ( if the string it's empty it' means that the query was successful without any mistakes)

```
String error = MainFrame.dataBase.updateResumen(resumen, resumen.getIdFiltro());
```

**How comes that my Table knows that the value changed?**

Comment: What cell renderers are you using?  What type of `TableModel` are you using?  How is the data being managed between the the database the `TableModel`?  For this and better answer, try providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: check the question again please

Comment: What about the column classes?  Are you using any custom cell renderers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default [renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for a cell of type `Object.class` is "a label that displays the object's string value." Unless your implementation of `TableModel` override's `getColumnClass()` to return some other value, your result is not unexpected. You might compare this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553842/230513) using `DefaultTableModel` to your implementation.

Addendum: *How does my table know that the value changed?*

`JTable` is a `TableModelListener`; any change to the model is (or should be) propagated to the table. Absent a [complete example](http://sscce.org/), I'm guessing that you are using a second table, `table2`, to edit a copy of certain data obtained from the original, `table1`.

- Verify that you are copying the data in `getResumen()` and not just copying a reference to the `table1` model.
- In your implementation of `setValueAt()` in the `TableModel` of `table2`, update the model of `table1`. The exact mechanism depends on your `TableModel`; two approaches are contrasted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13628183/230513).

Addendum: *I'm not using another table…I'm passing a reference to my internal frame*.

The same principles would apply. As an alternative to directly coupling the models, let the table's model be a `PropertyChangeListener` to the internal frame, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523401/230513).

Comment: would you check the answer again, I added some info :)

Comment: I've elaborated above; please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: I'm not using another table, I've used a JCalendar and a JTextField, the most obvious answer seems to me that I'm passing a reference to my Internal Frame and that's why whenever one change the one one inside my tableModel also changes... I'll try to change that and see if it's changes.. also it's kind of hard to do a SSCCE about this for me since I use a Designer for my windows (I'm awful at coding interfaces)

Comment: then wrote a new question, there to decribe everything from your commnents here, because are more important, valuable, than everything from your original question, note nobody be able to understand your class or components hierarchy, not (for me empty) constructor, etc, post an SSCCE

Comment: @nivde92: Thank you for clarifying; more above.