# Firing itemStateChanged event on Combo box inside jTable

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jtable, tablecelleditor

My problem is that I want to have a itemSateChanged listener on a combo box which is inside a jTable. When I change the values of the combo box I want data added to a cell in the respected row of the jTable.

This is the code where the combo box is created.

```
public void setUpSectionColumn(JTable table, TableColumn statusColumn) {
    //Set up the editor for the sport cells.
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.addItem("Lending");
    comboBox.addItem("Childen Lending");
    comboBox.addItem("Reference");
    comboBox.addItem("Special Collection");

    statusColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));

    //Set up tool tips for the sport cells.
    DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer =
            new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    renderer.setToolTipText("Click for combo box");
    statusColumn.setCellRenderer(renderer);
}
```

This is the method I have come up with for the listener which does not work.

```
public void fillTable2() {
    jTable2.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent evt) {
            int row = jTable2.getSelectedRow();
            String section;
            if (row == -1) {
                section = "Lending";
            } else {
                section = jTable2.getValueAt(row, 3).toString();
            }
            int accessNo = bdao.getLastAccessNo(section);
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
            Object[] rowdata = {Integer.toString(accessNo), "", ""};
            model.addRow(rowdata);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: yes is possible, but in most cases isn't there some reason to override JComboBox and with ItemListener, I'd be override setValueAt in DefaultTableModel, generate value for concrete row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), you can use a `JComboBox` as a `TableCellEditor`. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513) using `DefaultCellEditor`.

[image]