# How to properly use TableCellEditor in my case in JAVA?

Tags: java

I want to created an editable cell, how should i do that?

Comment: Personally I'd an an InputListener to the JTable, capture the user's input and modify the TableModel based on that input. Then update the Table with the modified TableModel. Seems like less hassle.

Comment: inputListener? but eclipse does not offer that kind of listener, but ill try to use it.

Comment: My bad, I meant KeyListener. You can build an InputMethodListener from scratch, but that's hell. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Comment: @Gorb i tried to use InputMethodTextChanged but nothing happened

Comment: yeah i tried keylistener too, but didn't work, i guess it really needs a cell editor? but if you have other easier ideas please suggest. Im in great need of help :(

Comment: Looks like you need a `CellEditor`. Look at `DefaultCellEditor` and how to write your own. I'm not sure where to start myself, catching input events in a JTable isn't something I've had to do before.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a comment on this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513), a `TableCellEditor` serves the `JTable` *view*. Instead, let your *model* calculate the dependent value when related cells in the same row are changed. You can do this in your implementation of `getValueAt()` or `setValueAt()`.