# Object in JComboBox in JTable is not associated with same object in combo list

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

my problem is that when I put Object to table in cell with CellEditor set to work as JComboBox and it's fine, but when click on the cell i got list with Objects, but selected one is not that which were in cell before, but just first on the list. Is there simple way to fix it?

```
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    data.get(row).values.set(col, (Device) value);
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
}
```

and

```
for(int i = 0; i < deviceTable.getModel().getColumnCount(); i++){

        ExtendedAbstractTableModel model = (ExtendedAbstractTableModel) deviceTable.getModel();

        JComboBox<Device> combo = new JComboBox<Device>();

        for(Device value : model.columnsCombo.get(i)){
            combo.addItem(value);
        }

        TableColumn columnModel = deviceTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        columnModel.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combo));
}
```

Comment: Any code? How do you work with the table/combobox?

Comment: i updated post with code

Comment: Best if your code is a [minimal complete runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please check out the link in my comment above. If your posted code complies with this standard, you will likely get better help, quicker.

Comment: code posted in your question talking about nothing, question in this form isn't answerable here, again for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTable/XxxTableModel stored in local variable

Comment: Works with `DefaultCellEditor`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what was wrong. I didn't override equal method in my class, and that is why these components couldnt recognise same item. Anyway, thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513), [`DefaultCellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html) handles this for you. You're adding multiple instances in a loop; a single instance can handle the entire column. `DefaultCellEditor` works by overriding `setValue()` in the nested [`EditorDelegate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.EditorDelegate.html). It's not clear how you've defeated this feature, but understanding the default may guide your search.

```
public void setValue(Object value) {
    comboBox.setSelectedItem(value);
}
```