# Sum and multiplication of values in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, sum

I can not view each value on the same line. It is displayed per column. Every dealer in the total column line should display the sum of all values.

I do not know how to display line by line.

```
String[]entete= {"Revendeur/Montant","5000","3000","1500","800","600","500","400","REMISE","TOTAL","CREANCE"};
Object [][]donnees= {{"Patrick",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,""},
                     {"Marie",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,""},
                     {"Christian",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,""},
                     {"Fabian",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,""},
                     {"TOTAL",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,""}};
private void setTableModelListener() {
    tableModelListener = new TableModelListener() {
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            int lastRow = model.getRowCount()-1 ;
            int lastColumn = model.getColumnCount()-2  ; //Colonne total
            int rowCount = model.getRowCount();

            if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE && e.getColumn() < lastColumn && e.getFirstRow() < lastRow && e.getLastRow() < lastRow ) {            
                int row = rowCount;
                int value = 0;// on initialise le résultat
                int value1 = 0;
                int value2 = 0;
                int value3 = 0;
                int value4 = 0;
                int value5 = 0;
                int value6 = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                    value += 5000*(int) model.getValueAt(i, 1); // cumul montant
                    value1 += 3000*(int) model.getValueAt(i, 2); 
                    value2 += 1500*(int) model.getValueAt(i, 3); 
                    value3 += 800*(int) model.getValueAt(i, 4); 
                    value4 += 600*(int) model.getValueAt(i, 5); 
                    value5 += 500*(int) model.getValueAt(i, 6); 
                    value6 += 400*(int) model.getValueAt(i, 7); 
                }

                model.setValueAt(value, 0, lastColumn);
                model.setValueAt(value1, 1, lastColumn);
                }               
            }
      };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Override `getValueAt()` in your [`TableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) to return the correct value for cells in the `TOTAL` row and column. The correct value may be calculated by invoking `getValueAt()` in a loop, as shown in your `TableModelListener` example. In this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513), the value shown in each row of the second column depends on the value chosen in the third column of the same row.